# How to load and show images from google.images using AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, google-image-search

I'm investigating a if it's possible to do this, what I'd like to do is to retrieve the search from google images and show the result in AS3, first, is this even possible?, if so, do you have an idea how to achieve it?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the google [custom search api](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview).

You will get the result as a json stream or an atom feet. But you will be restricted to 100 search calls a day, unless you pay good money to the folks at google.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info, I guess I will stop looking for a way then :p.